# Failing to run .WAR using java -jar

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

On an early stage of development of my Spring Boot project I was used to run the application using java -jar build\libs\online_store-0.1.0.jar. Now I need to deliver a WAR. I followed the links below to build a deployable WAR file with Gradle. After that I was able to deploy the resulting built file on Tomcat 8 webapp directory and it is working fine. But I also need to run the embedded server using java -jar. Every time I try to do it (java -jar build\libs\online_store-0.1.0.war) I get a FileNotFoundException related to some missing dependency JAR (please see the stack trace below). After I add the corresponding dependency to the requiresUnpack option the error message changes but I am afraid I will never finish adding dependencies. What am I missing to get the WAR file both deployable and runnable by java -jar? Thanks in advance.

```
requiresUnpack = [ "org.webjars:less", "org.webjars:jshint", "org.webjars:emberjs", 
    "org.webjars:handlebars", "org.webjars:coffee-script", "org.webjars:jslint", "org.webjars:json2",
    "org.webjars:jquery", "org.webjars:handlebars", "org.slf4j:slf4j-api"
     ]
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging

Snippet of stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\hcorzo\workspace\online_mvp\online_store\build\libs\online_store-0.1.0.war!\WEB-INF\lib\validate.js-0.8.0.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at org.webjars.urlprotocols.JarUrlProtocolHandler.getAssetPaths(JarUrlProtocolHandler.java:54)
        at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.getAssetPaths(WebJarAssetLocator.java:91)
        at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.getFullPathIndex(WebJarAssetLocator.java:121)
        at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.<init>(WebJarAssetLocator.java:152)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.WebJarsResourceResolver.<init>(WebJarsResourceResolver.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceChainRegistration.getResourceResolvers(ResourceChainRegistration.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistration.getRequestHandler(ResourceHandlerRegistration.java:164)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry.getHandlerMapping(ResourceHandlerRegistry.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:409)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c82d476.CGLIB$resourceHandlerMapping$33(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c82d476$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c23c9ca.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c82d476.resourceHandlerMapping(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\hcorzo\workspace\online_mvp\online_store\build\libs\online_store-0.1.0.war!\WEB-INF\lib\validate.js-0.8.0.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.webjars.urlprotocols.JarUrlProtocolHandler.getAssetPaths(JarUrlProtocolHandler.java:36)
        ... 43 more
```

And this is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/sbuettner/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
        classpath 'ro.isdc.wro4j.gradle:wro4j-gradle-plugin:1.8.0.Beta3'
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.6.RELEASE"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'wro4j'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: 'war'

dependencyManagement {
     imports {
          mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix:1.1.0.RELEASE'
     }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'online_store'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

war {
    baseName = 'online_store'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/sbuettner/maven' }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    versionJQuery = '2.1.1'
    versionBootstrap = '3.2.0'
    versionAngular = '1.3.8'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.grupomedicus.store.server.UiApplication"
    executable = true
    requiresUnpack = [ "org.webjars:less", "org.webjars:jshint", "org.webjars:emberjs", 
    "org.webjars:handlebars", "org.webjars:coffee-script", "org.webjars:jslint", "org.webjars:json2",
    "org.webjars:jquery", "org.webjars:handlebars", "org.slf4j:slf4j-api"
     ]
}

bootRepackage {
    mainClass = "com.grupomedicus.store.server.UiApplication"
}

bootRun {
    addResources = true
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

webResources {
    bundle ('core') {
        js 'js/**/*.js'
        preProcessor 'jsMin'
    }
    bundle ('angular-bootstrap') {
        js "webjars/jquery/$versionJQuery/jquery.min.js"
        js "webjars/angularjs/$versionAngular/angular.min.js"
        js "webjars/angularjs/$versionAngular/angular-route.min.js"
    }
    bundle ('angular-bootstrap') {
        css "webjars/bootstrap/$versionBootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        css 'themes/default/main.css'

        cssRewriteUrl()
    }
    assets {
        include 'themes/default/images/**'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-core")
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3'
    compile(group: 'de.infinit', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure-wro4j', version: '0.0.6')
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis"
    compile "org.springframework.session:spring-session"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul"
    webjars "org.webjars:jquery:$versionJQuery"
    webjars "org.webjars:angularjs:$versionAngular"
    webjars "org.webjars:bootstrap:$versionBootstrap"
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6')
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.13'
}
```

Comment: You cannot run a WAR file with `java -jar`. You'll need to setup your build so that you can create both an executable JAR file and a WAR file.

Comment: I used to think that but this post says the opposite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538788/spring-boot-war.  And this is a quote from the Spring Boot docs: "If you’re using the Spring Boot build tools, marking the embedded servlet container dependency as provided will produce an executable war file with the provided dependencies packaged in a lib-provided directory. This means that, in addition to being deployable to a servlet container, you can also run your application using java -jar on the command line". Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting, I didn't know that.